# $_SESSION doesn't work properly

Tags: php

Does anybody know why the following code doesn't work properly?

```
function LinksPage()
{
    $ClickedWord = $_GET['clickedword'];
    foreach($_SESSION['Links'] as $key=>$value)
    { 
        if ($key == $ClickedWord)
        echo $key."  ".$value.' <br />';
    }
}
```

When I check `$ClickedWord`, `$_SESSION['Links']`, I see that there is a key in `$_SESSION['Links']` that matches `$ClickedWord` but when I run the program if doesn't generate output.

Comment: try debugging $_SESSION['Links'] with var_dump($_SESSION['Links']);

Comment: Maybe there is a space after the content of `$ClickedWord`. So, if your `$key` contains `test` and your `$ClickedWord` contains `test ` it won't match. Try trimming the white spaces and other characters from the `$ClickedWord` like so `$key == trim($ClickedWord)`.

Comment: @ Thomas Cantonnet: can you please read my comment to the next answer.

Comment: @ Shed: I checked trim. nothing changed!

Comment: I see that you have slashes for clickedword : \'Advise \', could you elaborate on that ? You should var_dump($_GET['clickedword']) and compare it to the output of var_dump($_SESSION['Links']);

Comment: @Thomas Cantonnet I changed the code to:                      function LinksPage()
{
 $ClickedWord = var_dump($_GET['clickedword']);
 echo '<br/>';
 foreach(var_dump($_SESSION['Links']) as $key=>$value)
 {   
  if ($key == $ClickedWord)
      echo $key."  ".$value.' <br />';
 }
}

Comment: and still "if" doesn't execute. the out put is as follows: string(14) "'Corporation '" 
array(4) { ["sources "]=> string(45) "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewable_energy" ["Advise "]=> string(53) "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moseley_Royal_Commission" ["Corporation "]=> string(53) "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Corporation_(Motown)" ["traditional "]=> string(44) "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_IRA" }

Comment: @Thomas Cantonnet: thanks. your suggestion helped me to understand that I have saved "clickedword" in a wrong way. now it works.

Comment: @ Shed: thanks. I used your suggestion somewhere else in my program and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just fine. What's wrong is either `$_SESSION['Links']` or `$_GET['clickedword']`. Add the following debugging code in `LinksPage`:

```
echo '$_GET["clickedword"]: ';
var_export($_GET['clickedword']);
echo '$_SESSION: ';
var_export($_SESSION);
```

Most likely, the `$_SESSION['Links']` hasn't been set for the session in use, or you set `$_SESSION['links']` (with a lower-case L) instead.

Comment: I added what you said with a little change and this is the output: $_GET['clickedword']: '\'Advise \' 
'$_SESSION['Links']: 
array ( 'sources ' => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewable_energy', 'Advise ' => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moseley_Royal_Commission', 'Corporation ' => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Corporation_(Motown)', 'traditional ' => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_IRA', )

Comment: @nasi Are you absolutely certain the echo is not executed? Try replacing it with `die("found item");`

Comment: The ouput for var_export($_GET['clickedword') really is `'\'Advise \' '`?

Comment: @Volkerk I've just copied the browser output and pasted it here

Comment: @phihag yes I am. I tested your suggestion, no aoutput!

Answer (score 0):

nasi, Try this

```
$_GET['clickedword'] = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454193/session-doesnt-work-properly";
$ClickedWord = @$_GET['clickedword'];
$_SESSION['Links'] = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454193/session-doesnt-work-properly";
foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$value)
{ 
    if ($value == $ClickedWord)
    echo $key."  ".$value.' <br />';
}
```

Comment: @ bharanikumar Bs: ok. your code works. but based on your example I don't understand what I should change in my code to make it work.

Comment: `code` foreach($_SESSION['Links'] as $key=>$value)  Change it to foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$value) `code`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if ($key == $ClickedWord)
```

with

```
if ($value == $ClickedWord)
```